# What is the best way to compare objects in 2 collections, find equal objects and change objects' properties using Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have 2 collections of objects, let us say User:

Set usersFromDb;

Set usersPack;

```
public class User {
private String name;
private String email;
private boolean isActivated;
..
}
```

I need to compare objects in these 2 collections, if Set usersFromDb contains equal users as in Set usersPack, we must set the field isActivated to TRUE for these users in Set usersFromDb.

We can do it with nested for each loops:

```
for(User userD : usersFromDb){
    for(User userP : usersPack){
        if(userDb.equals(userP)){
            userDb.setActivated(true;)
        }
   }
}
```

How can we do it using Stream API?
I have tried smth like this

```
usersFromDb.stream().filter(d -> d.equals(users.stream().findFirst().get())).peek(d -> d.setActivated(true));
```

but have not succeeded.

Comment: `usersFromDb.stream().filter(usersPack::contains).forEach(user -> user.setActivated(true));`

Comment: This is no real advantage of using streams in this example. Because you seem only to be interested in the side effects (the call the `setActivated`) a loop is as clear and pretty as a stream here.

Comment: But you can simplify your code by getting rid of the inner loop and instead call `usersPack.contains(userD)`, as in MarcoLucidi's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `equals()` and `hashCode()` are consistent in your objects:

```
userFromDb.stream().filter(u -> usersPack.contains(u)).forEach(u -> u.setActivated(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Few notes, first:

1. Nothing was executed because the Stream was not closed with a terminal operation (such as `forEach`, `close` or `collect`.
2. The peek is for inspecting the item inside the Stream pipeline.

You should use `Stream::map` to change the object and `Stream::collect` to collect to a `List`:

```
List<User> users = usersFromDb.stream()                          // Stream<User>
                              .filter(usersPack::contains)       // if found in usersPack 
                              .map(user -> {                     // map to a User
                                        user.setActivated(true); // ... that is activated
                                        return user; })
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());     // List<User>
```

Comment: It is a misunderstanding that `peek` is only for inspecting the elements. The documentation says that it "...exists mainly to support debugging". But if you happen upon one of the rare cases where it is useful then there is no reason not to use it. And it is certainly preferable to use `peek` than to abuse `map` to do operations like this one, that involves no mapping but only side effects! This solution has all the same disadvantages of using `peek`, but is also bigger and less clear.

Comment: But, additionally, `peek` is not a good solution either, it is better to avoid side effect in the stream pipeline. It is clearer and less error prone to use `forEach`, as in MarcoLucidi's answer.

Comment: @Lii: I didn't say "only". You misinterpret my answer. Moreover, "inspection" is not different from "debugging" in the Stream API context.